# What constitutes indirect inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance

What do we mean when we say "All classes either directly or indirectly inherit from class `Object`"? What constitutes a class indirectly inheriting the methods declared in its indirect superclass?

Can we say that a class indirectly inherits methods declared in one of it's indirect superclasses, regardless of the fact that the method defined in the superclass may have been overridden whilst propagating down the inheritance hierarchy, thus comments such as the above are based on the fact that the subclass inherits *some* method with the same signature as that declared in the superclass.

Alternately, can we only ever say that a class indirectly inherits the methods declared in one of it's indirect superclass if and only if the class is inheriting THE method declared in it's indirect superclass, that is the method has not been overridden whilst propagating down the inheritance hierarchy, and the class is inheriting the method with the same implementation as that defined in it's indirect superclass.

Answer (score 10):

By indirectly inheriting, they mean that you extend another class that in itself extends Object. Directly inheriting from Object would mean that you either explicitly stated `extends Object` on your class signature, or you didn't define another class it should extend (in which case it extends `Object` directly anyway by definition.)

In terms of specific methods, you only inherit the one that was "last overriden" in the hierarchy. So if I'm inheriting from a class that inherits `toString()`, I'll only inherit the overriden version, not the original from `Object`.

Comment: Thank you and I understand that which you say but my question is regarding the conditions in which the comment "All classes either directly or indirectly inherit from class Object" is correrect.

Comment: @helloRichie It's always correct, regardless of what methods are overriden along the way any class still inherits from `Object` since it can still be treated as an `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

`Class1` indirectly inherits `Class2` when you use `"is-a"` more than once to describe their relationship (remember that `"is-a"` relationship is transitive).

Example: a `red-apple` is-a `apple` is-a `fruit` is-a `consumable`. In this example, `red-apple` indirectly inherits from `fruit` and `consumable`. `red-apple` directly inherits from `apple` (only one `is-a` transition used)

Answer (score 1):

The question about indirect inheritance of class was already answered. So I add on methods.

I think what is important here is the difference between class interface (signatures of available methods, not java mechanism of interfaces) and class behavior - the implementations of available methods. In your question about methods you can say that class indirectly inherits methods regardless of whether they were overridden by intermediate classes, and without any other details it means inheriting interface. To set the context of phrase to behavior meaning you must explicitly state that implementation of method X is taken from class Y.